# How can I display files that were written to on a specific date

Tags: command-line, files, directory

l have a folder composed of both files and subfolders (of files). l would like to display all the files  `*.pth.tar` written between 23 and 28 february 2018. Is this possible?

What is the command do I need to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You find files *modified* between a range of dates using the `find` command's `-newermt` test e.g.

```
find path/to/folder/ -name '*.pth.tar' -newermt '23 Feb 2018' ! -newermt '01 Mar 2018'
```

The `!` is a logical negation operator. From `man find`:

> ```
>    -newerXY reference
>           Succeeds  if  timestamp  X of the file being considered is newer
>           than timestamp Y of the file reference.   The letters  X  and  Y
>           can be any of the following letters:
>
>           a   The access time of the file reference
>           B   The birth time of the file reference
>           c   The inode status change time of reference
>           m   The modification time of the file reference
>           t   reference is interpreted directly as a time
> ```